# Laravel: method to set the value of a custom primary key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, orm

My `Document` model has a custom primary key name, so I typed:

```
class Document extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'fluxo_mensagem_id';
```

After this, I suppose Laravel to know my primary key name and then I wouldn't expected to have to type it manually every time I need to set its value. Something like:

```
$document = new Document;
$document->setPrimary($pivot->id);
```

Instead of:

```
$document = new Document;
$document->fluxo_mensagem_id = $pivot->id;
```

> For more details, my partial ER diagram:

[image]

**Question 1**

Laravel provides some method to set primary key values dynamically after custom names defined on model class?

**Question 2**

On `document` table, the column `fluxo_mensagem_id` is a foreign key that references `id` `fluxo_mensagem` pivot (intermediate) table. There's some way to "associate" (as we can do with [Belongs To relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)) `Pivot` object to a `Document` model?

For example:

```
  $pivot = $mensagem->fluxos()->first()->pivot;
  $document = new Document;
  $document->fluxoMensagem()->associate($pivot);
```

This would fit the problem because his intention is to set the foreign key on the child model.

Comment: Q1: Why would you need to change primary key? Q2: In the document, you can manually change document `fluxo_mensagem_id` prop: `$document->fluxo_mensagem_id = $pivot->id;`

Comment: @SérgioReis Q1: I don't want to change primary key, I'm looking for some method on model creation.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Question 1: You can set the primary key value as any other, but you need to set the $incrementing = false, otherwise it'll be saved as 0.

```
/**
 * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $incrementing = false;
```